# Convert data frame to one cell vector(s)

Tags: r

I would like to convert the columns from a dataframe into one cell.

Currently I am getting the following:

```
beruf <- c(" 2", " 3", " 5", NA, "aa", "bb", "cc", NA)
contact <- c(" 2", NA, NA, NA, "aa", NA, "ccda", NA)

beruf     <- as.vector(as.matrix(beruf))
contact     <- as.vector(as.matrix(contact))

# append to data frame
df.buffer <- data.frame(as(beruf, "character"), as(contact, "character"))
```

My Output is like that:

[image]

However, I would like to get the following:

[image]

Any suggestions how to get the desired output?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `data.frame(deparse(beruf), deparse(contact))`, but I don't see why you would want this.

Comment: I have to ask why you would want that? You want the values as strings? data.frames don't like to hold nested structures. Each column should be an atomic vector otherwise you run into trouble

Comment: or `data.frame(x = I(list(beruf)), y = I(list(contact)))`

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff I get some data from a website and I get tables with different rows. The problem is that each table scraped from the website has a different length. However, I only need some info from the website. So during this step I am going to get the desired information from the tables and then search for just the ones needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in `base`:

```
sapply(df.buffer, paste, collapse = ",")
```

or a little longer in `data.table`:

```
setDT(df.buffer)[,lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",")]
```